# Error when setting the center of a map as a dictionary value

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an app developed with django: an user enters an integral in a form an gets redirected to a page that, depending of the input, it shows a map or another. The value that the user has entered is in the variable ***{{linea_numero}}***

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var LatLangParada = [
        ["{lat: 40.969092, lng:  -5.675925}"],
        ["{lat: 38.737370, lng: -9.147660}"],
        ["{lat: 40.412944, lng: -3.681914}"],
        ["{lat: 41.385691, lng: 2.153859}"],
    ]

    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: LatLangParada[{{linea_numero}}],
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
</script>
```

I get the error

> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in
>   property lat: not a number

I tried to delete the ***""*** of the coordinates, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the sintax fo lat lng literal is  {"lat": 40.969092, "lng":  -5.675925}
so

and for center you should use only a lat lng literal not all the collection

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var LatLangParada = [
        [{"lat": 40.969092, "lng":  -5.675925}],
        [{"lat": 38.737370, "lng": -9.147660}],
        [{"lat": 40.412944, "lng": -3.681914}],
        [{"lat": 41.385691, "lng": 2.153859}],
    ]

    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: LatLangParada[0],
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: answer updated ... you pass the entire collection but for center need  only one point